# Macros/variables in Sybase IQ - changing a string?

Tags: macros, sybase, sap-iq

I'm dealing with dates quite a bit, doing `select` statements like the following for many different years:

```
select sum(sales) from DM.SALES_SHEET where sale_date < '1995-01-01';
select sum(sales) from DM.SALES_SHEET where sale_date < '1996-01-01';
select sum(sales) from DM.SALES_SHEET where sale_date < '1997-01-01';
...
```

Shouldn't there be a more efficient way of querying these data? I would like to create a variable that I could just update every time I needed another year. This would look somewhat like the following (I don't know if `declare` is the right command, either).

```
declare @specific_date string;
set @specific_date = '1995-01-01';

select sum(sales) from DM.SALES_SHEET where sale_date < @specific_date;
```

Is there a way to use a string for this type of variable? My `sale_date` column is string.

Answer (score 0):

```js
create procedure dynamic_date (@specific_date date)
as
begin

declare @specific_date_string varchar(500)
set @specific_date_string = 'select sum(sales) from DM.SALES_SHEET where sale_date < ' + @specific_date + ';'
exec @specific_date_string

end

--example: exec dynamic_date 'your_date'
```

Here you go friend! Cheers